# Homology of Mapping Cone is Trivial--Proof from scratch

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $(A_*,\partial )$ and $(B_*,\partial' )$ be chain complexes, $f:A_*\to B_*$ a chain map and suppose that the map $f_*$ it induces on homology is an isomorphism.

The mapping cone $(C_*,D)$ is defined by $C_n=A_{n-1}\oplus B_n$ and $D_n(a_{n-1},b_n)=(-\partial_{n-1}a_{n-1},f_{n-1}(a_{n-1})+\partial'_n b_n).$

Now, define $A_n^+=A_{n-1}.$ Then, using the maps $i:b\mapsto (0,b)$ and $p:(a,b)\mapsto a$, there arises in the usual way, the long exact sequence

$$ \cdots \rightarrow H_{n+1}(C)\overset{p_*}\rightarrow H_{n+1}(A^+)\overset{f_*}\rightarrow H_n(B)\overset{i_*}\rightarrow H_n(C)\overset{p_*}\rightarrow H_n(A^+)\rightarrow \cdots $$

Then, $H_n(C)$ is trivial for all $n$. The proof is easy (but hadn't occurred to me, ugh.) I wanted to do it using the basic facts about the chain complexes involved, to get an idea of how they work.

There is a proof from scratch of essentially the same thing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645714/f-induces-an-isomorphism-in-homology-iff-the-mapping-cone-of-f-is-contra/1645731#comment5907907_1645731) but I think I found a problem with it, and made a comment there. I would appreciate feedback on my comment there as well as on my attempt here at a from scratch proof, which follows.

What I have so far (dropping the subscripts and primes on the differentiation operators):

Let $(a,b)\in Z_{n}(C).$ Then, by exactness, we have have the following:

$1).\ p_*([(a,b)]=[a]\Rightarrow a\in Bd_{n}A^+$ and $2).\ i_*([b])=[(0,b)]\Rightarrow (0,b)\in Bd_{n}C.$

So, there is an $a'\in A_n$ and a pair $(a'',b')\in C_{n+1}$ such that

$3).\ \partial a'=a$ and $4).\ (-\partial a'',f(a'')+\partial b')=(0,b).$

Combining these facts we get $(a,b)=(a,0)+(0,b)=(-\partial (a'+a''),f(a'')+\partial b').$

If I could show that either $f(a')=0$ or $\partial a'=0$, I would then have $(a,b)\in Bd_nC,$  which is what I want.

Comment: It's your question why $C$ has trivial homology, or why the given sequence is well-defined and exact?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably not the answer you are looking for, but here is a proof using model category theory. Somehow, it says that this is a result not about chain complexes per se, and it is a motivation not to dive into chain complexes details.

In any model category $\mathcal C$, the mapping cone $C_f$ of $f:X\to Y$ is defined as the homotopy pushout of $\ast \overset !\gets X \overset f\to Y$. Computing homotopy pushout in a model category goes as follow: take a cofibrant replacement $X'\overset q\to X$ of $X$. Factor $fq$ as $pi$ with $p$ acyclic fibration and $i$ cofibration. Factor $!q$ as $p'i'$ with $p'$ acyclic fibration and $i'$ cofibration. Then take the ordinary pushout of $\bullet \overset {i'} \gets X' \overset i \to \bullet$. This is summed up in the following diagram:

[image]

In particular, $q,p,p'$ are weak equivalences, so if $f$ is also a weak equivalence, we get that $i$ is an acyclic fibration. It follows that its pushout $j$ also is such. In the end, we have a commutative triangle:

[image]

where $p'$ and $j$ both are weak equivalences, which yields that $C_f \to \ast$ is also a weak equivalence. Otherwise put, $C_f$ is contractible.

---

If you play that proof in your favorite model structure on chain complexes for which weak equivalences are the quasi-isomorphisms, you get the result you wanted.

Comment: I do not know much about model categories, except for the basic acyclic models theorem. I do know some category theory, though, (I have read CWM and Awodey's book) so I wonder is there a way to make your proof more understandable on that basic level? If so, I will gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is why $C$ has trivial homology: $f_*$ is an isomorphism, so $p_*$ and $i_*$ must both be zero maps.

Comment: Yes, I know, but then how is it immediate from this that $C$ has the trivial homology? I am using the fact that $i_*$ and $p_*$ are zero maps to prove that $Z_n(C)=Bd_n(C).$  If it's trivial, could you point out why?

Comment: If, in an exact sequence, one of the terms $X$ has both its incoming and its outgoing maps equal to zero, then $X$ has to be 0. Proof: The image of the incoming map is 0 because the incoming map is 0. But that image is also the kernel of the outgoing map, and that kernel is all of $X$ because the outgoing map is 0.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I still would like to do a proof from scratch, to see how the "innards" of these chain complexes work. I am just starting to learn about homology theory, and am reading Rotman. If you critique my proof and/or the comment I made on a similar question (the link is cited above), I will be glad to accept your answer.